# IIS not running *.cs code

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I have deployed asp.net web forms website on windows server 2012 and linked with a subdomain (using Plesk panel).
Now, the website is not running any code-behind files even the `Page_Load` is not being called.
For testing purposes, I added the javascript `alert` in `Page_Load`; it didn't show any message, but it did show when I added `alert` in *.aspx file, it did show.

I didn't get the actual reason, but seems like IIS configuration error may exist.
Help me resolve the issue, will be appreciable.

Comment: Did you check your event viewer? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: it didn't work for me.